# Microsoft Word 2010 - Inserting Multiple Images into a Table

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have 100 thumbnail images which I need to insert into a table in Microsoft Word 2010.

Rather than clicking Insert > Picture > *select picture* > Insert - or even `Ctrl + Y` after inserting an initial image - I would like to know if there is some way that I can select all 100 thumbnails and have them inserted into the table, each to its own cell.

Each thumbnail image needs to be on its own line, in its own cell.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now resolved this problem using VB.

Comment: Could you perhaps post the VB code here, so others may use/modify it if they need it?

Comment: It was obtained by doing some searching online, but I no longer have access to the document that it was used in, unfortunately.